# How do I get the display name of a driver in Windows 10?

Tags: cmd.exe, windows-10, drivers

## Background

I want to output the full Display name of a driver in Windows 10. Specifically, I want this property of the driver in Windows 10:

[image]

I am trying a specific part of the Display name of a driver in Windows 10.  So far I have tried various versions of [`driverquery`](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/list-device-drivers-driverquery-command-prompt) and [`Get-WindowsDriver`](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/free-software-to-list-installed-drivers-on-windows-10) but neither display the full display name in the picture above.

## What I tried

The closest info I get is the following by running `driverquery /FO LIST /V > drivers.txt` with the following details:

```
Module Name:       Ser2pl
Display Name:      Prolific Serial port WDF driver
Description:       Prolific Serial port WDF driver
Driver Type:       Kernel 
Start Mode:        Manual
State:             Stopped
Status:            OK
Accept Stop:       FALSE
Accept Pause:      FALSE
Paged Pool(bytes): 28,672
Code(bytes):       258,048
BSS(bytes):        0
Link Date:         9/16/2021 5:34:02 AM
Path:              C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\ser2pl64.sys
Init(bytes):       4,096
```

I know these are one in the same because the driver date is identical:

[image]

There *has* to be a way to get the full `Prolific USB-to-Serial Comm Port (COM3)` name.  Therefore my question is:

## Question

How do I get the full Display name of a windows driver in command line?

Comment: `COM3` isn't part of the driver name, but the COM port it's connected to.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you have for an index, but Display name is in the registry.
[e.g., HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class{4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0005\DriverDesc]
[DeviceMgr vs. Regedit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwOjn.png)

reg query KeyName /v DriverDesc

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for one of these powershell cmdlet:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver | Select DeviceName
```

or

```
Get-WmiObject win32_systemdriver | select Displayname
```

you can also display only one driver, for example:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_systemdriver | select Displayname | where Displayname -match "Prolific USB-to-Serial"
```

this will only return display names that contain the words Prolific USB-to-Serial.